# Connect two small networks each using own DSL to one shared server for applications and data storage

Tags: windows, network-share

Per davidgo I am rewriting this:
Company A has a network, DSL modem/router, switch, server DHCP running Server 2008, and workstations.  While Company B has a network, DSL modem/router, switch, and IP phones connected to their DSL service.  All of Company B workstations are connected to Company A switch/server to access server data.  I need to be able to connect Company B workstations to their own network, modem/router, switch and DSL service, but also connect them to Company A server for applications and data storage.  The server has two NIC ports with only one configured for the original Company A network.  I can get the specifics including a drawing, layout, wiring, switches, and IP addressing.  Is this something anyone can assist me with remotely?

Comment: You might want to rewrite your wall of text to be more concise(and junk the irrelevant history?) and attach a diagram. I started reading it and gave it up as to difficult to wade through.

Comment: A diagram would be helpful - one thing which I can't grasp from your post is company A and B appear to use the same switch, but are supposed to have different DHCP servers - Can you clarify? Also are/can your switches be clan capable, and what routers are you using? Absent evidence I would use DD-WRT on each routers network and assign 2 WAN ports on each - one for external connectivity and the other to the peer router. I would make sure IP addresses are in different subnets and route appropriately.

Comment: Now Company B has their ws network connected to Company A network switch to access the server programs. Those computers are using Company A DSL service as well. So those computers are getting IP addresses from the server, but need to be connected to their switch/router/DSL service. Only Company B IP phones are connected to their switch/router/DSL service. I know the IP phones are getting a totally different IP address. I also know Company B has a router performing DHCP with the same IP addressing as Company A which needs to be changed. Company A switch is 3Com and not sure Company B switch.